# How to produce a .o file from code using Arduino IDE (primarily for LGPL3 compliance)

Tags: arduino-ide

I spent a great deal of time looking for any posts regarding this and came up empty.

The reason I needed to do this is that I am working on some proprietary code that will be released in an embedded device, but makes use of an LGPL 3.0 licensed library which requires (4.d.0) that I release "corresponding application code in a form ... permit the user to recombine or relink the application with a modified version of the library."

Since the application is on an embedded device, the "corresponding application code" works out to the pre-link .o file which is normally well hidden in the Arduino process.

Comment: Owen DeLong, as in the Internet Engineering arena? Just curious... it's been a long time.

Comment: Just FYI, the Arduino core lib is also LGPL. https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/Arduino.h

Answer (score 2):

To extract the .o produced during compilation in the Arduino IDE, do the following:

1. Go to the Arduino->Preferences menu item. This will open a preferences window.
2. In the preferences window find the line that says "Show verbose output during" and make sure that compilation is checked. (you can leave upload on or off as you prefer).
3. Click "OK" to close the preferences window.
4. Compile (or compile and upload) your Sketch.

You will get lots of extra output. In the white text, you will either see messages about files being compiled or about "using previously compiled file". In either case, there will be a path provided which will indicate where your Sketch was compiled. On my Mac environment this is `/var/folders/<long random string>/T/arduino_build_<number>/sketch/<sketch_name>.ino.cpp.o`

The line where your sketch is compiled is very long, but the path is also visible in most of the library lines and you can just work down into `.../sketch/...` instead of `.../library/...` instead of scrolling so far to the right on the exactly correct line.

To find the exact line where your sketch is compiled, look for the line directly below a line which simply says "Compiling sketch..."

I know this is rather basic (now that I know how to do it), but it took quite a bit of digging to find it and I figured others might want an answer that's searchable.

Comment: Note that the Arduino IDE defaults to compile with [link-time optimization](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.5.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fwhole-program) enabled, which will make it harder for another user to do the final link, as “bytecode files generated in one version of GCC do not work with an older or newer version of GCC.” I suggest you compile with `-flto -ffat-lto-objects` in order to alleviate this problem.